# saving specific data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I've been workinig on a project which uses *AngularJS* and have been using LocalStorage for storing data. But I'm facing some difficulties in separating specific data from localstorage before i clear it.

Following is the sample data stored in localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("favClub_"+userId,JSON.stringify($scope.favClub));
localStorage.setItem("cityOfBirth_"+userId,JSON.stringify($scope.cityOfBirth));
```

All the keys stored have userId appended so they all are unique.

#### Example:

```
UserID: john
Key: favClub_john & cityOfBirth_john
```

Now I need to keep the data *favClub* and *cityOfBirth* of all the users before i clear the storage on log in.

I was thinking of having an array to store the required data and iterate through the local storage and keep the data which matches my requirements. I was wondering how we can loop through localstorage with such dynamically varying keys.

Sorry if the questions been asked. I tried searching but couldn't find similar question. Any input would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: localStorage is like cookies, it's local to the end user. You should NOT be storing the data for all users in localStorage!

Comment: I would suggest create single object that holds all value and store it in localStorage as string. Convert it into object in your code and loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't iterate over `localStorage` keys. But you could use different approaches, for example:

```
localStorage.setItem("myAppData", JSON.stringify(['john': {'cityOfBirth': 'Granada', 'favClub': 'C.B. Granada'}]));
```

So then you would be able to get your `myAppData` and iterate over it.

Comment: yup ! thanks ! did that . created an array of objects based on key-value pairs ! works like a charm ! thanks !